# C syntax with multiple pointers and parentheses

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Could someone explain to me the following syntax:

```
typedef struct {
    int (*jac) (void *state, float * J);
} aType;

(...)

aType myVar;
```

I can access myVar.jac, but what are "state" and "J" and how to access them?

Thanks!

Comment: `myVar.jac` is a pointer to a function which is taking `void*` and `float*` and returning `int`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`state` and `J` are not fields of your struct.  They're parameters of the function pointer `jac`, which *is* a member of your struct.  This points to a function which takes a  `void *` and a `float *` as parameters and returns an `int`.  You can use it like this, for example:

```
int myfunc(void *state, float *J)
{
   ...
}

...

a_type myVar;
myVar.jac =  myfunc;
char buffer[100];
float f;
...
myVar.jac(buffer, &f);
```